# Can I GET from private bucket from Lambda using curl without presigned url?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

On my Lambda I am using binary programs for audio conversion, like `curl {urls} | converter` - this is a good approach because curl stream files and `converter` transcode them during fetching. I used presigned urls but faced with a problem that when `Signature` param contains `+` (and maybe `=`, `/`) I get 403. I tried `curl '{urls}'` and `%2B` instead of `+` - no luck. My current code validates presigned url for `+` and if found - wait one second and generate new presigned url, but waiting on Lambda is non-free.

My Lambda has the policy for getting files from this bucket - but looks like only through presigned urls.

Comment: If you find that you have to use pre-signed URLs then your Lambda function does not have the correct policy to access the files in S3. I'd fix that first. Then I'd change the code to use boto3 to stream the contents of the file into the Lambda.

Comment: I need presigned urls only for `curl`.

Comment: @jarmod is it possible to stream multiple files simultaneously to the lambda from S3 using boto3?

Comment: I don't see why not, but be aware of the Lambda timeout. That said, why not just process one per Lambda, based on an audio file being dropped into the S3 bucket?

Comment: A `+` is url-escaped as `%2B`, not `%2F`, which is the code for `/`.  While a bit unorthodox, what you are doing is perfectly viable.  `curl` should work just fine with pre-signed URLs, as long as they are correct.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes I agree that curl must correctly handle presigned urls from boto3 but in CloudWatch I see 403 - and only for urls with `%` :( I copied the same url and tried to curl it on Mac and Ubuntu and it was correct